# get javascript to write to variable rather than document.write

Tags: javascript, variables, timestamp, document.write

I have the following javascript that prints the timestamp:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
<!--
var currentTime = new Date()
var hours = currentTime.getHours()
var minutes = currentTime.getMinutes()
var seconds = currentTime.getSeconds()
var month = currentTime.getMonth() + 1
var day = currentTime.getDate()
var year = currentTime.getFullYear()
document.write(hours + "" + minutes + seconds + month + "" + day + "" + year)
//-->
</script>
```

However I want to use this timestamp in many places in the page, how can i call it like $timestamp so i can control where its placed?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Answer: Set a variable with the string...

Comment: You could use a template language like [Handlebars.](http://handlebarsjs.com/) or you could just use document.write in every place you want to add the time.

Comment: How do I set a variable with the string?

Answer (score 1):

Set a variable, like:

```
var timestamp = hours + "" + minutes + seconds + month + "" + day + "" + year;
```

and later in code use that variable to show info in your page, like:

```
var container = document.getElementById('container1');
container.innerHTML = timestamp;
```

where 'container1' is a html element like span, div, p, etc. ex:

```
<span id="container1"></span>
```

Comment: OP wants to use this timestamp in many places of the page. Could you modify your solution for this case?

Comment: I dont want to call it wherever there is an id called container1. Is there not a way to reference it like ${variable} and it displays there?

Comment: But the timestamp in Valentin's example is actually a string which you can use anywhere. You print it out or add it to any HTML element any way you want. If you're asking whether you can show it like document.write("bla {1} bla", timestamp) i don't think this is possible in standard Javascript but maybe there's some library out there that does this (in my opinion it's not worth the effort to go out and look for such a library :)

Answer (score 0):

answer

```
<script>
    function startTime()
    {
    var today = new Date();
    var h = today.getHours();
    var m = today.getMinutes();
    var s = today.getSeconds();
    // add a zero in front of numbers<10
    m = checkTime(m);
    s = checkTime(s);
    document.getElementById('txt').innerHTML=h+":"+m+":"+s;
    t=setTimeout('startTime()',500);
    }

    function checkTime(i)
    {
    if (i<10)
    {
    i="0" + i;
    }
    return i;
    }
</script>
<span id="txt"></span>
<script type="text/javascript">
  startTime().swap('txt');
</script>
```